# Image files not loading through jquery ajax from server cpanel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cpanel

I don't know if this is a duplicate question but i have searched and couldn't found solution for this

I am newbie in cpanel and i recently uploaded my project in it. Now there is a part in my website where i am loading a folder of images through jquery ajax. Now this was working perfectly in the local server xampp but not in the server it keeps giving 404 error that means that the files not being discovered by the ajax script. For security reasons i am not going to share the links right now but i will explain the full procedure

These are the location of those folders. These scripts are in js folder. But obviously it is included in index page. anyway lets move

```
var svgFolder = "img/svg/";
var productImagesFolder = "img/ImagesForProducts/";
```

Following are the ajax scripts that i am using to load the images of these folders

```
$.ajax({
    url: svgFolder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|svg)$/)) {
                $(".svg-shapesDiv").append("<img src='" + svgFolder + val + "' id='svg-shapes' loading='lazy'>");
            }
        });
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: productImagesFolder,
    
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|jpg)$/)) {
                $("#avatarlist").append("<img style='cursor:pointer;' class='img-polaroid' src='" + productImagesFolder + val + "' loading='lazy'>");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

All of this is working fine in localhost server but for some reason when i uploaded them in the cpanel it stopped working.

I tried hard coding the `img` tag like this

```
<img src='img/svg/file.svg' id='svg-shapes' loading='lazy'>
<img src='img/ImagesForProducts/file.png' id='svg-shapes' loading='lazy'>
```

**Things i tried**

And this works fine so i think that the ajax is not figuring out the address. I also tried to search the image through link in the browser like this `domainname.com/img/svg/file.svg` and it works fine as well. i also tried to give ajax the path like this `domainname.com/img/svg/file.svg` but it doesn't work. I checked the file capitalization etc but everything is correct

If this was a stupid question then i am sorry but i don't know that what i am doing wrong and i am also new to cpanel and live hosting stuff.

Comment: Is there some index.php file under img/svg/ that gathers the list of files to return to the ajax call? If there is no script on the server side that builds up the html you receive back then are you relying on indexes? If so then indexes might be disabled by default, you'd want a htaccess to enable them but better yet have a server side script to gather the file names and return them in a better format like json rather than html to be processed client side.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I don't have any index.php file under img/svg/ and the thing is i don't have much knowledge of htaccess, i don't know why an index.php file is needed inside img/svg folder, i don't know about indexes. Could you send me a link from where i can learn this stuff or just the term. I am sorry for being this dumb the thing is i code and all but never tried to upload etc and never took any tutorial for this stuff because it wasn't needed so could you tell me this so i can learn it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the response to my comment it sounds as though your xampp has "indexes" enabled by default. Please see here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html

It may be that on your shared webhosting they are disabled by default and you would need to enable them for those 2 directories. As you are using cpanel please see here: https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/advanced/indexes/82/ but this can also be achieve by adding a .htaccess file to the 2 folders containing `Options +Indexes`.

The trouble with relying on indexes this way is that different servers could potentially return slightly different html so you could find that your xampp server returns html links (your JavaScript searches for anchor tags and gets the href from there) but the shared server may not return links it may just return the file names. Also with this html being returned your JavaScript has to parse that html, search all links and extract the href. I would therefore recommend writing a php script that gathers the relevant files and returns only those in JSON format. Much easier then for the JavaScript to parse and use and you now have full control of what is returned whether it is on your xampp server or other hosting. You can call this script whatever you want and you can place it wherever you want. You could even have one script that accepts query parameters from your AJAX call and from those it know which folder to look into and what types of files it must gather from the folder. This also has the advantage of keeping all other files in those folders hidden from prying eyes.